# How to find users not in *any* groups in WGM?

Tags: macos, server.app, serveradmin

In Workgroup Manager (Mountain Lion, but really any version), how can you get it to show all users who do *not* belong to a group?

Can't use the "by Group ID" thing in the Advanced Search, because that's just trying to match actual groups against your search term, not users who belong to groups.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, every user has a primary group.  I can't think of a way to create or modify a user so that this is not true...  Unix doesn't allow it.  Do you mean to look for users which aren't in any group except for the primary group?

Comment: Fair enough, yes — I'd forgotten about the primary group, as it goes completely unused in my context. So yeah, not in anything except that. :)

Comment: (I've got hundreds of users, and almost all are in classroom groups, but I know there are a handful who have left the school and should be deleted. Just don't have any way of identifying which users they are.)

Comment: WGM is not going to be of much help.  You're going to need to dive into `dsmemberutil` and the `dscl` command lines.  This superuser post has some good material: http://superuser.com/questions/279891/list-all-members-of-a-group-mac-os-x